# SQL create view statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am new to SQL Developer. I have to create a view to approach
the sample output list below:

[image]

The table structure is:

```
SITE(Site_ID, Region, Description, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude); 
MEASUREMENT(Site_ID, Recorded_On, Name, Value, Outlier_Indicator);
```

Here is my script, it is working as I followed the advices.

```
create view Site_Outlier_Incidents AS 
    select 
        Site_ID, Name, Outlier_Indicator,
        count (SITE.Site_ID) as Number_Of_Incidents
    from Site SITE
    left join Measurement MEASUREMENT on MEASUREMENT.site_ID = SITE.Site_ID
    where Name = 'E.Coli'
    group by
        Site_ID, Name, Outlier_Indicator;
```

Comment: Typo? You've missed *comma*: `...Outlier_Indicator, count (SITE.Site_ID)...`.

Comment: And there's an extra right parentheses at the end. Remove it.

Comment: Use `create or replace view` instead of `alter view`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited all of the typing mistakes but there is still an error report: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: show the edited sql please. You might still have some erros

Comment: I tried to insert count and group by into create view statement but I couldn't make it right :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `create or replace view` instead of `alter view`

Comment: May I be able to combine those two statements into one create view statement? How do I approach it?

Comment: the syntax is `create or replace view view_name as (your query);`